# R capitalize roman numerals only in string

Tags: r, gsub, stringr, regexp-replace

If I have a vector with the following:

```
people <- c("PERSON I", "PERSON II", "PERSON III", "PERSON IV")
```

To turn them into title case, I used the following:

```
people <- str_to_title(people)
```

Now I have the following

```
> people
[1] "Person I"   "Person Ii"  "Person Iii" "Person Iv"
```

What do I to capitalize the Roman numerals only like this?

```
"Person I"   "Person II"   "Person III"   "Person IV"
```

Or is there a way to convert the all-caps into the last vector without using `str_to_title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `substr`, `sub`, and `paste`:

```r
people <- c("PERSON I", "PERSON II", "PERSON III", "PERSON IV")
people <- paste0(substr(people, 1, 1), tolower(sub("^\\S(\\S+).*$", "\\1", people)),
                 " ", sub("^.*?(\\S+)$", "\\1", people))
people

[1] "Person I"   "Person II"  "Person III" "Person IV"
```

Comment: How would I approach this if 1. string preceding the roman numerals have spaces, and 2. if not all of them had roman numerals?`people <- c("JOHN SMITH I", "MARY SUE II", "JOHN F KENNEDY III", "DWAYNE THE ROCK JOHNSON IV", "SOME GUY)`?

Comment: That's really a totally different question.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same format, i.e. two words separated by a space, you can use the following:

```
sapply(strsplit(people,' '), function(X){paste(str_to_title(X[1]), X[2]) })
```